# Django - Save() will save some fields but not all updated fields

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

My API receives a remote cURL request with JSON data and saves it to database. It is taking in good values and assigning them to the object but when object.save() is called only a item or 2 is updated in database when 4 items are actually updated. The second part of this is it only happens on the production server but not developers server (runserver) where it runs and saves just fine.

In the code, we print each object item after we have set it's new value to verify we have accurate data and fits model requirements.

Here is Model

```
class LUMAgentConfig(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('team', 'clientID', 'computerID'),
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team_lum_agent_config', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clientID = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    computerID = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    isEnabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rebootRequired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lastScanDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    lastUpdate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    packageManager = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default='')
    packageManagerVersion = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default='')
    updateCount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.team.id) + " -> Agent -> " + str(self.computerID)
```

Here is our simplest hack of View.py we tried during testing.

```
        if validateJSON(myJson):
            data = json.loads(myJson)
            computerID = data['computerID']
            clientID = data['clientID']
            scriptVersion = data['scriptVersion']
            packageManager = data['packageManager'] 
            packageManagerVersion = data['packageManagerVersion']         
            print("computerID - > " + str(computerID))
            lumConfig = LUMAgentConfig.objects.get(team_id=team.id, clientID=clientID, computerID=computerID)
            print(lumConfig.clientID)
            lumConfig.packageManager = str(packageManager)
            print(lumConfig.packageManager)
            lumConfig.packageManagerVersion = str(packageManagerVersion)
            print(lumConfig.packageManagerVersion)
            lumConfig.updateCount = int(len(data['packages']))
            print(lumConfig.updateCount)
            lumConfig.lastScanDate = timezone.now()
            print(lumConfig.lastScanDate)
            print("PM:[" + str(lumConfig.packageManager) + "] Ver:[" + str(lumConfig.packageManagerVersion) + "] Pgs:[" + str(lumConfig.updateCount) + "]" )
            lumConfig.save()
```

We are using PSQL and Django 4.2

During run on production server we printed the following object items during a normal save request.

```
computerID - > 05b1d029-3fc4-aee2-9337-22523ef0052d
U3F1aWRXb3Jrcw==
apt
2.4.8
43
2023-05-02 16:50:08.965043+00:00
PM:[apt] Ver:[2.4.8] Pgs:[43]
```

The only thing updating in the database is the lumConfig.lastScanDate.  If we manually modify the data in the database it does not overwrite the current data with blanks.

We have modified the code to specifically save the fields by name and have modified the code to save after each column being set with no change in results. We have placed it in a try statement to see if we could get a error generated but that did not generate any errors for us.

**Update**

After putting code through a blender trying different things to get data to save, I started to focus on the model. I first deleted the table in SQL and recreated it, retested and still no data. I looked at the model, the 3 columns that aways were missing data, all had defaults but 2 had default = ''. I modified one of the defaults to instead place 'Not Acquired' in column if data is not present, applied and migrated model and retested the request in production.  What do you know! the data for all 3 missing columns show up now in database. The code had been put back to it's original version for all current testing.

If anyone can explain why such a minor change in a model would have such a drastic effect and why it only seemed to effect the production server and not also effect the development server.

```
    packageManager = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default='Not Acquired')
packageManagerVersion = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default='')
updateCount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.models import transaction
       
if validateJSON(myJson):
    data = json.loads(myJson)
    computerID = data['computerID']
    clientID = data['clientID']
    scriptVersion = data['scriptVersion']
    packageManager = data['packageManager'] 
    packageManagerVersion = data['packageManagerVersion']
    with transaction.atomic():
        lumConfig = LUMAgentConfig.objects.select_for_update().get(
            team_id=team.id,
            clientID=clientID,
            computerID=computerID
        )
        lumConfig.packageManager = str(packageManager)
        lumConfig.packageManagerVersion = str(packageManagerVersion)
        lumConfig.updateCount = int(len(data['packages']))
        lumConfig.lastScanDate = timezone.now()
        lumConfig.save(update_fields=["packageManager", "packageManagerVersion", "updateCount", "lastScanDate"])
```

Comment: Please add explanation